# Do I need to make a Bachelor's thesis to apply to a master's degree from a top 100 University in the world?

Tags: thesis, masters

So let me tell you my story: I studied Industrial and Systems Engineering in the 24th best university in my country, which is around number 1683 in the world. I am from Mexico and thankfully our government is eager to pay our full tuition if we are accepted to one of the best 200 Universities in the World to study a Master's Degree, mainly in engineering.

My main challenge at this moment is to be accepted in a masters' program at an International University. My grades are good, I have a "promedio" of 92, which is pretty high, although not the highest of my class, and I had outstanding results in the professional test. Because of these results, I was exempted of having to do a bachelor's thesis.

- Should I sacrifice my opportunity of earning working experience to dedicate myself to make a good Thesis? I am eager to do so if I really need to.

  Thanks a lot to the people that took the time to read this.

Comment: Ideally, you should have one question per post... And some of these questions, only you can answer. You wrote a fair amount of text (don't forget the commas!), and you described a delicate situation. If you could restrain the questions and provide only the relevant information, the answers should be more informative... In the meanwhile, check those universities to see what is usually involved in their masters'. You should get a better idea of what is a masters' and what you'll need to do...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just erased the questions and made it a little bit more brief.

Answer (score 4):

I've never been on an (academic) admissions committee, but I can hardly imagine that, instead of reading the title of still another bachelor thesis, I find "exempted by university from writing bachelor thesis because of my course performance near the top of class," and consider that a negative. So I don't think you should sweat that. In most fields, undergraduates are not expected to have done research prior to taking up graduate studies; exceptions, as I have learned here, include math where this appears to be more commonplace. For some of your target fields (eg, supply chain management), I know it isn't, or at least wasn't, as some of my research was arguably on the most theoretical end of it, but I had no relevant experience with it prior to writing my paper; but that could have changed. I don't know about the others.

In terms of being accepted at a good school, the ranking of your alma mater is probably what I would worry about most. You'll need strong letters, ideally from people known internationally (check their publications; ask them). You should definitely approach someone from your U.S. experience for a letter.

Finally, your first, second, and last question (as well as part one of your question 4) are highly personal decisions that you are unlikely to get feedback on here. They are off-topic, and even if they weren't, I wouldn't ask such questions on an anonymous internet forum. Ask friends, family, any mentor, and yourself.

Comment: This doesn't quite fit your edited question. I'll keep it up a bit; maybe some is of use.

Comment: Your answer is of a lot of use, I edited my questions because I had asked too many and I thank you for answering them.

Comment: While it probably really won't be considered that negatively, one should still keep in mind that "course performance near the top of class" is still course performance, which - depending on what kinds of tasks courses in the respective university system include - is still something very different from the experience of writing a thesis (and I'm not even referring to theses that require any real research), and at least top performers in exams can nonetheless have a very hard time when writing a thesis (or the other way round).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I agree, and there are certainly fields where it will count negatively. I just think that if it is university policy to exempt extremely high performers from writing a thesis, it would be unfair to hold it against an applicant; and I want to believe most departments will see that similarly, That said, you are certainly right: it's a different skill set with evidence missing.

Comment: @gnometorule: Absolutely, I'm aware the student has no influence on such a policy. (And it is of course still open whether courses maybe included something somewhat similar to a thesis, anyway, maybe at a smaller scale at least.)

Answer (score 0):

Different countries have difference expectations at the Bachelor's level, which means they have different requirements for entry into Masters. For example, it is unusual to do research as part of an engineering degree in Australia. I therefore suspect you could apply to an Australian university to do a Masters in Engineering without complication, and there are several in the top 200. In addition, you would be coming with funding, which (I am sad to say, but good for you) makes you a more attractive applicant.

I suggest you approach it from the other direction. Get the list from your government of which universities it considers acceptable, then look at a couple from each country in the list to see which ones seem to not require research. Once you have identified suitable countries, look at all the universities on the list from that country and find a program you like.